# Domain expiration date and redirect

Tags: php, html, web

My website redirect me to another page and it told me my domain is expire but date of expiration is 2015-07-30, what's happened to my website?
[Gender Select](http://www.genderselect.ir)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's happened, but it's now ok

Answer (score 0):

It expired a few days ago.. March 9 (This domain name expired on Mar 9 2015 01:04:46:000PM )